# SQL like with additional characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a textual search on a `MySql` table and I want to find words that may end with certain characters.

Here's an example. The search is for the word `clip`. I want my query to find the word `clip,` or `clip?` but not the word `clipping`.

So far this is what I tried:

```
select * from product where title like '%clip%'
```

also finds the word `clipping`, which is not good.

```
select * from product where title like '% clip %'
```

doesn't find `clipping` but also ignores the word `clip` when there's a comma right after it, `clip,` and that's also not good for me.

Is there a way to specify that the query would ignore letters, but include characters like `,` or `.` or `?` or basically any other character I choose?

Comment: title  like '%clip_'

Comment: This finds words with anything after clip but not a space character, which I definitely need to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that matches word boundaries:

```
... where title regexp '[[:<:]]clip[[:>:]]'
```

If you have a lot of data and find yourself doing lots of searches like this, it may be a good idea to create a [full text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) and then use `match...against`:

```
... where match(title) against ('clip');
```

Comment: I like this ans. So elegant.

Comment: @Joni I already have a full text index on the column. What would be my match against syntax?

Comment: I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `REGEXP`.

```
where title REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*'
```

The following is a demo.

```
mysql> select 'the paper clip is white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*';
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 'the paper clip is white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*' |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  1 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'the paper clip? is white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*';
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 'the paper clip? is white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*' |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'the paper clipping is white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*';
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 'the paper clipping is white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*' |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'the paper clipis white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*';
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 'the paper clipis white' REGEXP '.* clip[,.? ].*' |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 0 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: How do I add space to this both in the beginning and the end of the search term?

Comment: provide a sample which you want to match with spaces?

Comment: For example the paper clip is white. Also the paper "clip" is white.

Comment: Updated. But obveriously, @Joni 's ans is more beautiful and simple.

Comment: I guess I should accept Joni's answer. Thanks though.